# Why does Javascript forEach not allow early termination using break or return

Tags: javascript, foreach

I know that this behaviour is well known and well documented:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

> There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by
>   throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method
>   is the wrong tool, use a plain loop instead. If you are testing the
>   array elements for a predicate and need a Boolean return value, you
>   can use every() or some() instead. If available, the new methods
>   find() or findIndex() can be used for early termination upon true
>   predicates as well.

```js
var theSecond = findTheSecond()
console.log('theSecond is: ' + theSecond)

function findTheSecond(){
  [1,2,3].forEach(function(e1) {
 console.log('Item:' + e1)
  if(e1 === 2) {
   return(e1)
  }
});
}
```

My question is why was JavaScript designed like this? Was this an oversight or a deliberate design decision for the language?

Comment: It certainly is _deliberate design decision_... There are other methods of array to handle _otherwise_ scenarios...

Comment: Because it is `forEach` not `forEachUntilStopped`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These functional iterator methods don't "break" like normal "for" loops probably because when you want to do "forEach" they probably were thinking you intentionally want to do something "for each" value in the array.  To do what you want to do there as in "finding" the correct item, you can use "find"

```js
var theSecond = findTheSecond();
console.log('theSecond is: ' + theSecond)

function findTheSecond(){
  return (
    [1,2,3].find(function(e1) {
      console.log('Item: ', e1);
      return e1 === 2
    })
  )
}
```

Forget the "for loop" which is imperative, get "functional"! There's plenty of methods on the array to choose from i.e. map, reduce, etc.

Comment: I am going to reason about this based on your imperative/functional comment, which makes sense to me. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with a short cut, if necessary.

```js
var theSecond = findTheSecond();
console.log('theSecond is: ' + theSecond);

function findTheSecond() {
    var result;
    [1, 2, 3].some(function (el, i) {
        console.log('Item:' + el);
        if (i === 1) {
            result = el; 
            return true;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```